# 'datalab connect' get stuck after entering the passphrase

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I usually connect to my datalab VM (after starting it) using the "datalab connect " command.

Now it get stuck and doesn´t connect after I enter the passphrase key.

I still can SSH into the VM.

Running `docker ps -a`, apparently the docker is up and running:

but looking at its log, I can see only:

```
ramurti@datalab-ramurti ~ $ docker logs 69a17993dec4
2017-11-21 03:15:14 +0000 [warn]: pattern not match: "-- Reboot --"
```

Does anyone know what it mean?

Another clear problem: the /mnt/disks/datalab-pd directory is 100% full. It's only 10GB and there is a swapfile of 9.7GB. My datalab had 15GB of ram, so this issue seems related to the one reported here:

https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1192

I'm unsure if I can simply delete this file or not. Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I basically deleted the swapfile and that fixed the problem.

One strange thing, though, is that I also increased the size of the additional disk, from 10GB to 40GB, but it didn't really change the available size of the disk which is mounted. Now I'm suspecting that Google is billing me a 40GB disk, while offering only 10GB...